# How to retrieve key substring and count by this substring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following dictionary in Python:

```
OrderedDict([('data(xxx_a1)_first_type', 0.12),
             ('data(xxx_a2)_first_type', 0.14),
             ('test(xx_b15)_second_type', 0.15)])
```

Is there any way to count `first_type` and `second_type`, and calculate the average value per type?

The expected result:

```
type         avg_val
first_type   0.13
second_type  0.15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
list_Tuples = [(z, np.mean([y for x,y in v.items() if x.endswith(z)]), len([y for x,y in v.items() if x.endswith(z)])) for z in ['first_type', 'second_type']]
pd.DataFrame(list_Tuples, columns=['type', 'avg_val', 'count'])
```

Output:

```
    type         avg_val  count
0   first_type   0.13     2
1   second_type  0.15     1
```

where `v` is the data.

Comment: Great answer. How can I count entries per "type"? It was also part of my question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks :) Check the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are only two types (otherwise use a dict to store the lists by type) :

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from statistics import mean

data = OrderedDict([('data(xxx_a1)_first_type', 0.12),
                    ('data(xxx_a2)_first_type', 0.14),
                    ('test(xx_b15)_second_type', 0.15)])


firsts = []
seconds = []
for key, value in data.items():
    if key.endswith("first_type"):
        firsts.append(value)
    else:
        seconds.append(value)

print("type", "avg_value", sep="\t\t")
print("first_type", mean(firsts), sep='\t')
print("second_type", mean(seconds), sep='\t')
```

Comment: use a `defaultdict` to generalise the logic further

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.groupby` assuming the data is ordered.

**Ex:**

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import groupby

d = OrderedDict([('data(xxx_a1)_first_type', 0.12),
             ('data(xxx_a2)_first_type', 0.14),
             ('test(xx_b15)_second_type', 0.15)])

for k, v in groupby(d.items(), lambda x: "_".join(x[0].split("_")[-2:])):
    val = [i for _, i in v]
    print("{} {}".format(k, sum(val)/len(val)))
```

**Output:**

```
first_type 0.13
second_type 0.15
```

---

Or using `dict.setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
result = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    key = "_".join(k.split("_")[-2:])
    result.setdefault(key, []).append(v)

for k, v in result.items():
    print("{} {}".format(k, sum(v)/len(v)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group the values, then apply [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) to get the average:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import OrderedDict
from statistics import mean

data = OrderedDict([('data(xxx_a1)_first_type', 0.12),
                    ('data(xxx_a2)_first_type', 0.14),
                    ('test(xx_b15)_second_type', 0.15)])

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in data.items():
    *_, key = k.split('_', 2)
    d[key].append(v)

for k, v in d.items():
    print('%s %.2f' % (k, mean(v)))
```

**Output:**

```
first_type 0.13
second_type 0.15
```